# How do you hide thumbnail image in Wordpress post?

Tags: css, wordpress

How do you hide featured thumbnail image from showing up in your Wordpress posts?

I am using the simplelin theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "Additional CSS" add the following:

```
.post-thumbnail > img { display:none }
```

I am not sure how many themes this works in, but I know it works for simplelin.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with this additional CSS -

```
.entry-thumbnail { display: none; }
```